# How does a switch mode power supply without a control IC work?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have a very old computer (1987) that all of a sudden shut down, followed by a bang (blown fuse) a couple of seconds after that.

Here's a look at the PSU

[image]

Upon opening the PSU I noticed the following

- Fuse blown violently
- Power transistor completely shorted (all 3 legs)
- Schottky diode shorted (package with 2 diodes , one diode shorted)
- An NPN transistor with surface damage (and also not passing the multimeter-diode test)

After replacing all those parts the fuse is no longer blowing, but I am getting zero DC output on all rails.

I'm not really comfortable with doing measurements on the AC side of the PSU when it is switched on, so I am wondering what other kind of diagnostics I can do.

I read that a violently blown fuse most likely results in lots of failed components (see above) and further diagnostics include :

- Checking the transistor
- Checking the bridge rectifier and other diodes on the PCB
- Checking some resistor values
- Checking capacitors
- Checking control IC

Not visible in the picture above but beneath the heatsink of the power transistor is a 2SD667A NPN transistor that had some damage. I replaced that one with a BD139 (due to the lack of a proper replacement)

Here's a better view of what is beneath that heatsink (removed the bulk caps)

[image]

However I could not find a controller IC to drive the power transistor on this PSU.

I guess I always (wrongly) assumed there would be a control IC to turn on / off the transistor. Not knowing too much about how this could be achieved using discrete components, can somebody help me understand how such a circuit would look like and how this could have been implemented in this PSU ?

Comment: The oscillator controlling the switching of the transistor can be  something like a VCO where the voltage is the difference between the reference and the output voltages. May you can try tracing the control circuitry surrounding the transistor to see if some such circuit is present.

Comment: You may check the bottom side of the PCB as well since the control IC can be an SMD type glued to the bottom. If there's no IC then the converter can be **self-oscillating** type.

Comment: no components on the bottom side. all through hole components on one side.

Comment: What components should I be looking for for that VCO ? (added a picture to get a better view of what is sitting behind the bulk caps.

Comment: Power tranny is too slow look for >50MHz BW for the flyback circuit

Comment: *I always assumed there would be a control IC to turn on / off the transistor.* Why would you assume that? Before the 1990s there were few ICs available and the available ones were expensive so it was not uncommon to use only discrete components. Using an IC often makes the design easier (and cheaper) but that doesn't mean it cannot be done without an IC.

Comment: Guess I simply don't know how such a circuit would look using discrete components.

Comment: @ddewaele ICs are almost made of discrete components, so it shouldn't be too hard to imagine.

Comment: for the tranny frequency... I corrected the BD129 in the post as I used a BD139. This should be able operate at a frequency of 160Mhz. (the original 2SD667A datasheet mentioned a frequency of 140Mhz)